# Is it possible to See my secondary screen as PIP on my primary one

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, wayland

I have a setup where my secondary screen, actually a beamer, is behind my computer (in the back of my seat).

So when playing a video, I have to open it first, on my primary screen, then drag it to the secondary one. At this point, I don't see it anymore... So I use keyboard shorcuts (

> alt v + alt l

) to get VLC go fullscreen. Then I go to the sofa and watch my film.

This kind of works, but I have to remember the shortcuts, and the whole family depends on me to watch a movie...

I tried to clone the displays, but someone there is no suitable configuration that matches both displays (maybe frequency mismatch, as resolutions would match I think...).

So here is my question:

1. is the a solution to **see a secondary monitor as a picture in picture**
   on the primary one ?
2. alternatively, can I force a resolution to cloned displays, when monitor settings does not propose them ?

(as a side note, if that matters, my graphic card is an Intel HD 4000)

Comment: Your second question seems to be completely different from the first one.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto well, it is indeed, but it would solve the same problem for me: be able to interact with a secondary display I can't see from my seat

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to clone your screens using **arandr**? You can install it by using this command:

```
sudo apt install arandr
```

Once you have it **arandr** allows you to overlap or arrange your displays in the way you want. You can also resize them to make them fit as need.

[image: Arandr]